# scalaz Monoid for SortedMap

Tags: scala, scalaz

I believe scalaz has monoid instances for both Map and [SortedMap](https://github.com/S11001001/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/SortedMap.scala).

But this doesn't work

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> Map(1 -> 1) |+| Map(1 -> 1)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> import scala.collection.SortedMap
import scala.collection.SortedMap

scala> SortedMap(1 -> 1) |+| SortedMap(1 -> 1)
<console>:19: error: value |+| is not a member of scala.collection.SortedMap[Int,Int]
       SortedMap(1 -> 1) |+| SortedMap(1 -> 1)
                         ^
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either
```
scala> import collection.immutable.SortedMap
import collection.immutable.SortedMap

scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> SortedMap(1 -> 1) |+| SortedMap(1 -> 1)
<console>:19: error: value |+| is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Int]
       SortedMap(1 -> 1) |+| SortedMap(1 -> 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalaz provide immutable data structure instances only.

You should add `import scalaz.std.sortedMap._` and use `scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap` instaead of `scala.collection.SortedMap`.

```scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_201).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> scalaz.BuildInfo
res0: scalaz.BuildInfo.type = version: 7.2.30, scalaVersion: 2.13.1

scala> import scalaz.std.sortedMap._
import scalaz.std.sortedMap._

scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> scala.collection.SortedMap(1 -> 2) |+| scala.collection.SortedMap(1 -> 3)
                                          ^
       error: value |+| is not a member of scala.collection.SortedMap[Int,Int]
       did you mean ++:?

scala> scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap(1 -> 2) |+| scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap(1 -> 3)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,Int] = TreeMap(1 -> 5)
```

Comment: ah besides it having to be immutable, it seems a separate import of `import scalaz.std.sortedMap._` was necessary. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Scalaz will use SortedMap if second argument is SortedMap (like scala collections do) but this is implementation detail and you should not rely on it.

```scala
//If you only care about `Map` inteface then treat `SortedMap` as normal `Map`: 
val res = Map(1 -> 1) |+| SortedMap(1 -> 1)
println(res.getClass.getName) // scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

//If you really need to have access to SortedMap api then you can cast to it:
val res2 = res.asInstanceOf[SortedMap[Int, Int]]
```

**EDITED**
This is implementation detail and you should be aware of that! There should be better answer to this question that uses existing scalaz implementation for sortedMap!

I've no time to investigate more ... sory.

- Here is some implementations for SortedMap in scalaz but don't know how to use them :(. 
  https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/7e64f43872fc944b54a63e4262acaea2248f50c8/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/SortedMap.scala
- here is old implementation. I struggle with finding current one, but assume is similar. 
  https://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/Semigroup.scala.html#114426

key is here that we use `to` instance as a builder for result here.

```scala
//from implementation of |+|
from.foldLeft(to) { case (to, (k, v)) => to + ... }
```

**shortly**: Don't mark this answer as valid one: It is not. Probably you should not rely on implementation detail. Still it is possible and this answer could be helpful for someone.

Comment: Thanks Scalway! But does this mean the SortedMap instance is not used at all? If so why does it exist?

Comment: HEY: Please unmark my answer. It should work but It is wrong because it depends on implementation detail of scalaz. There should be better answer somwhere (in scalaz codebase there is special case for SortedMap) but I could not figure out how to use them. I've edited answer to answer why. Sorry for that... I've not tested it before properly.

Comment: Thank you. I have unmarked your answer. Hopefully someone else might shed some light on this!